# Vuetify stopped working when included in a Typescript-enabled Vue.js project

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-cli-3

I have recently tried to create a simple app that combines Vue.js, Vuetify.js and Typescript. However, even though at first Vuetify seemed to work when combined with Typescript, upon my most recent app compilation, all I get are error messages of the type **"Unknown custom component"**.

Here is the configuration for my `vuetify.js` file:

```
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi', 
  },
})
```

And here is the config for my `main.ts` file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import './registerServiceWorker';
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify.js';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  vuetify,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

I installed Vuetify using `npm install vuetify` and not through the Vue CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be any of a million things, but

1) confirm  you've properly setup [VuetifyLoaderPlugin in webpack.config.js,](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/a-la-carte) as that is what is intended for when you import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib', otherwise you would do the full imports:

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
```

and 2) try this instead of your last new Vue line:

```
let vue = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: router,
    vuetify: vuetify,
    render: (h) => h(App)
});
```

3) UPDATE as per your comment: you also need to make sure you have the right packages for the style to get loaded

> npm install sass sass-loader fibers deepmerge -D

Then in webpack.config.js, add something like this to the rules:

```
            { test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/, use: [isDevBuild ? "style-loader" : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                // Requires sass-loader@^8.0.0
                options: {
                    implementation: require('sass'),
                    sassOptions: {
                        fiber: require('fibers'),
                        indentedSyntax: true // optional
                    }
                }}
            ]},
```

or if using vue-style-loader (this is the example from the [vuetify quick start](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start), which basically I think you should take a look at in full to make sure you're not missing any other setup steps):

```
{
  test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
  use: [
    'vue-style-loader',
    'css-loader',
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      // Requires sass-loader@^8.0.0
      options: {
        implementation: require('sass'),
        sassOptions: {
          fiber: require('fibers'),
          indentedSyntax: true // optional
        },
      },
    },
  ]
},
```

Comment: I redid it so that it loads it from 'vuetify', not 'vuetify/lib'. This cleared the errors but now there is a weird error where I guess the elements are recognized but their styles are not applied - for example, a <v-btn> is styled as a normal <btn> tag.

Comment: @TKD21 updated my answer with what i think is the remaining problem

Comment: Using the sass-loader tip allowed me to see the styles but they don't look like the Vuetify I remember. For example, a <v-btn> looks like this in the problematic project (first image) --> https://imgur.com/a/MwVOfFD while a <v-btn> in a project, installed through the Vue CLI(using vue add vuetify in a non-Typescript project) looks like the second image in the gallery. Both buttons are using the same setup, yet look different.

Comment: @TKD21 try adding this: import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Comment: That did it, thank you so much! Vuetify documentation confused me a lot, thanks for the quick answers and help! I marked your answer as the correct one but you might want to add the import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css' line into your answer! Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Those who are still find trouble with Vuetify + Vue + Typescript.

```
vue create project-name
cd project-name
vue add vuetify
```

when your vuetify added, you will see under plugins folder, a file name vuetify.ts just created where you can custom your vuetify theme and also vuetify will be added to **main.ts** . Then you will able to find

```
node_module/vuetify/types
```

This file need to add in **tsconfig.json**

```
"types": [
  ...
  "vuetify"
],

// then add this
"typeRoots": [
  "./node_modules/@types",
  "./node_modules/vuetify/types"
]
```

Enjoy !!

Comment: More info here https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vue-cli-plugins/issues/112